# Raising Cauchy's integral formula to some power $n-1$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

For a course on Complex Analysis I was checking the solution to some problems the professor gave us. One such problem was calculating $\int_{|z|=1}e^z z^{-n}$ and the solution goes on to state the following:
Taking $f(z)=e^z$ then
$$
f^{(n-1)}(z) = \frac{(n-1)!}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=1}\frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta-z)^n}d\zeta
$$
I can see why, through Cauchy's integral formula we could have something like this but I don't yet understand where the factorial comes from or why we would have the denominator inside the integral raised to $n$. It seems strange to me.

Comment: Differentiate the Cauchy integral formula with respect to $z$ enough times, noting that you can commute the derivative and integral.

Comment: Ohh man, I thought it was raising to a power instead of derivation. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Oh, ok. You could write a variant of the Cauchy integral formula for the holomorphic function $f(z)^{n - 1}$, but the power would be on $f$ instead of the denominator.